# wxWidgets windows 10 taskbar progress bar for app

Tags: windows, windows-10, wxwidgets

I want to use the windows taskbar's progress bar to show that some resources are being downloaded. I am talking about this:

[image: enter image description]

I want to show what percentage has been done. How can I do that?
I am using wxWidgets-3 with C++. I am on windows 10 latest version.

Help appreciated. Thank you :-).

Comment: Also would appreciate if you could tell me if this is supported in earlier windows versions.

Comment: @stuartd I am on windows 10 and am not using C#, but C++.

Comment: [`wxAppProgressIndicator`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_app_progress_indicator.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you want is provided by MSW-specific [wxTaskBarButton](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.1/classwx_task_bar_button.html) which can (and should, if possible) also be used via a more portable [wxAppProgressIndicator](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.1/classwx_app_progress_indicator.html) which is also implemented for macOS platform.